# Is this a special case of the NP-complete set packing?

Tags: algorithm, np

I'm almost certain that my problem is equivalent to set packing, and thus, NP-complete, but I would like someone to verify.

I have the following situation:
There is a set of pens (i.e. universe).
A store sells bundles of these pens, which are subsets of that universe.
I know a guy who has certain pens (also a subset of the universe) from the store, but I have no idea which bundles he bought.
He might have lost some pens and gotten others from other bundles that his friends gave him.

What I want to do is map the bundles sold by the store into the subset of pens that my friend has so that I cover the highest amount of pens and the chosen bundles must not contain any pen which my friend doesn't have.
For example:

```
Possible Pens: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Bundles sold by store: {0, 1} | {0, 1, 2} | {2, 3} | {3} | {3, 4, 5} | {4, 5}
My friend has: {0, 1, 2, 3}
Here, there are perfect matches: {{0, 1, 2}, {3}} and {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}. 
These would be equivalent

Friend 2 has: {0, 2, 3}
In this case, there is no perfect match.
Possible matches are {{3}} and {{2, 3}}.
The best match is {{2, 3}}.
```

I this problem NP-complete given a number `m` of pens, a number `n` of bundles and a number `l` of my friend's pens ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: I already checked that out. I'm not really concerned with the smallest number of sets covering the universe (or the smallest 'weight' etc.). I'm more concerned about mapping subsets of the universe into another subset of the universe. This is why I thought it's more similar to set packing than set covering. Maybe I'm wrong though :)

Comment: Note that the bundles sold by the store have to cover the universe. However (and this is important), the set of pens that my friend has does not have to cover the universe and this is the set I want to fit the bundles in.

Comment: Might be more appropriate on the CompSci.SE site. This isn't about programming.

Comment: it is np complete and every np complete problem can be transformed to every other np complete problem. :)

Comment: Throw away any bundle that has an inadmissible pen, and take all others. There is no room to try any combinations of bundles. A bundle is either admissible, or it is not. Now if you want a *minimal* set of bundles that still covers his possessions, you have a set cover problem.

Comment: @MSalters you're right. I wasn't aware of those communities. Is there a way for me to transfer this question easily to one of those sites ?

Comment: @MattKo: Unfortunately, no. TPTB have decided that programming is more related to TEX typesetting than to Comp.Sci, so we _can_ move questions to TEXT.SE but not to CompSci.SE :|

Comment: @n.m. The set cover problem assumes that the bundles would cover the set of pens my friend has. That's not the case if you throw away inadmissible subsets. That's the point that I don't understand.

Comment: Let me explain it in more detail. Any bundle that has a pen that your friend doesn't have is a bad bundle. We will not take it, ever. We can exclude all bad bundles from further discussion. At this point any pen that your friend has which is not covered by one of the remaining bundles is a bad pen. No bad pen will be covered, ever. We can exclude bad pens from further discussion too. What remains of his pens is completely covered by what remains of the bundles. Where's the challenge?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made it much clearer. For some reason, I had the  'set packing' problem stuck in my head and wasn't able to change my mind here. Cheers :)